# Open window popunder by body click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to trigger `popunder` on **`<body>`** click.

Here is code https://shoppingbyte.com/test/
 (also on [github](https://github.com/hpbuniat/jquery-popunder)):

```
<h3>Testcase #3 (1 Popunder)</h3>
<pre>
  window.aPopunder = [
    [&#39;http://www.bing.com&#39;]
  ];
</pre>
<a href="#" onclick="$.popunder(this)">Open Popunder via Link</a></div>
```

As I am new in javascript and jquery. I need help, how can I open `popunder` on `<body>` click?

Thanks advance for your help

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Also, the code you've posted here doesn't do anything. `window.aPopunder` just creates a global property to an array with one item in it (another array). A pop under is a new window that is placed behind other windows. Your code doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: Could you please try adding onclick attribute of the body? `<body onclick="$.popunder(this)">...</body>`